# Tor Browser .dmg won't 'attach' on iMac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, tor-install

After downloading the Tor Browser to my mid 2011 iMac desktop running El Capitan, opening the disk image (dmg file) results in it rreporting that it is 'attaching'.  After a minute or so, it times out with no result.
I used Firefox to download.  AT&T is my ISP.  I am an average user as regards ability.
Any ideas? Tips? Thank you.

Comment: I found the answer to my question in this other post entitled: Torbrowser 5.5.5 auto exits when opening on El capitan. I was able to install the browser but only when I utilized the Administrator account.